# R - dot plot - colours of dots based on a range of values from a vector

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have to simply dot plot in R, with V1 vs V2 in the data shown here. I want to set the color of dots based on a range of samples from the `individuals` column. For example, Here the dots should be of three colours: one color for the range from `HG097 - HG101`, second color for the range `HG1941 - HG1950`, and the third color for range `NA18542 - NA18547`. The data is:

```
individuals V1       V2
HG097      -0.0181  -0.0818
HG099      -0.0188  -0.0808
HG100      -0.021   -0.0753
HG101      -0.0196  -0.0804
HG1941     -0.0206   0.0174
HG1942     -0.031    0.0075
HG1944     -0.0291   0.0454
HG1945     -0.0245  -0.0128
HG1947     -0.0184  -0.0065
HG1950      0.006    0.0167
NA18542    -0.0296   0.0899
NA18543    -0.0318   0.1012
NA18544    -0.0305   0.096
NA18545    -0.0317   0.1068
NA18546    -0.0315   0.1016
NA18547    -0.0332   0.098
```

Would the `split` function will work here along with the `plot`, as:

```
d <- read.table("data_file", header =T)
split(d, c(HG097:HG101) <- group1  
split(d, c(HG1941:HG1950) <- group2
split(d, c(HG18542:HG18547) <- group3
groups <- c("group1", "group2", "group3")    
col <- c("blue", "red", "green")
col.3 <- rep(col, each=groups)
plot(d$V1, d$V2, pch=19, col=col.3)
```

Thanks for solution.

Comment: Do you have other criteria to define the groups other then arbitrary ranges ?

Answer (score 1):

`split` splits across a grouping factor, which you don't have (in fact, it's what you need), so will not be useful here.

With base plotting, you can make a grouping variable which you can pass to `col`. In this case, `nchar` can conveniently do the trick, though otherwise you may need to use `rep` or regex to define your groups.

```
d$group <- nchar(as.character(d$individuals))

plot(d$V1, d$V2, col = d$group, pch = 19)
```

[image: base R grouped plot]

Note there's no legend yet, and the colors are just the standard ones, but these things are editable.

---

If you'd prefer `ggplot2`, you can define the grouping variable inline like

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(x = V1, y = V2, colour = factor(nchar(as.character(individuals))))) + 
    geom_point()
```

where factor defines it as a discrete instead of continuous variable. You'll end up with a nasty legend, though, so it may be better to mix approaches:

```
d$group <- factor(nchar(as.character(d$individuals)), 
                  labels = c('HG097 - HG101', 'HG1941 - HG1950', 'NA18542 - NA18547'))
ggplot(d, aes(x = V1, y = V2, colour = group)) + geom_point()
```

[image: grouped ggplot]